# Using definite article with adjective that doesn’t refer to a group

Tags: grammar

I’m trying to understand which option is grammatically correct and why:

> What is the size of **the computer**?

Or

> What is the size of **computer**?

I feel like the first one is correct but why we need the second ‘the’ here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because it refers to a particular size and a particular computer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Computer* is a "count" noun, so in the singular it always needs an article, except in certain constructions which allow articles to be omitted (for example, in some contexts, *and* linking things conventionally paired together, like *man and wife*, *horse and cart*).

None of these special constructions apply here, so *computer* must have an article. Whether it is definite or indefinite depends on what you want to say, but *What is the size of a computer*, while grammatical, is an unlikely thing to say, because computers vary so much in size.